# What is this part?

Tags: part-identification

I've been trying to source a new part for my cost but have no idea what it's called.

[image]

Can anyone tell what the broken part is. 
It is a BMW series 1 57 plate.

My friend thinks it is an exhaust bracket.

Comment: Any chance you can back out a little to give some context on this? Also what make, model, and year is the car?

Comment: Added a bit more information, but not near the car so can't get another picture.

Comment: @Terry, then at least tell us what area of the car this is at.  Under the hood?  Back of the car? etc...

Comment: @Terry Context would definetly help, I thought this was under the hood near the suspention. But to be an exhaust hanger it would have to be under the car. Where on the car are we looking in this initial pic?

Comment: It's at the back underneath near the exhaust.

Comment: Terry, where is the car located in thw world (don't get too specific). Is it in Germany? I think BMW handles all of their own car parts themselves and the short description makes it sound like a vintage auto. I have not heard of Series 1 cars in the USA or Canada so I am guessing this is EU or UK so check with BMW and if its a vinage auto, they might be able to suggest some places. Or, get ready to do a lot of searching for the part. Sorry I cannot identify it. I heard thw info from the old "Top Gear" programme from the days with May, Clarkson, and the other guy.

Comment: it looks like one of those plates that go from the subframe to the chassis

Answer (score 6):

I'd need *exact* details to confirm, but this should put you on the right track:

"Stopper, rear"

This genuine part fits your 2007 BMW 1 Series (E82,E88) 135i.

Stock Code  33316794866 ; 33316763411

Manufacturer    BMW

Categories  Suspension - Rear > Rear axle with suspension
Assemblies  Rear axle carrier

[BMW of South Atlanta Parts 2007 E82,E88](http://parts.bmwofsouthatlanta.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=258073&ukey_make=972&ukey_model=13423&modelYear=2007&ukey_category=17342)

Really curious how the ear got broken off that...  did you attempt the Rubicon?  8->

Comment: The ones you mentioned has no ear. How about this one: 33306778328? I wonder what mounts to the ear.

Comment: The exploded diagram shows the left one having the ear... but they resolve to the same part number.  I suspect it's a mounting point for a "sumthin" on a different vehicle that shares a common part?  A BMW dealer can resolve this question.  And if the ear isn't necessary, the part may not need replacement in the first place...